# Function which validates the coupon code for an item

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

In my coupon code i have added a category condition and when i add the coupon code in the cart it will validate and add the discount. I want to find the function which validates this to add a custom validation which will also check whether the item is discounted via catalog price rules. For that i have trouble finding the location of the method. Please guide me. I checked `Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php` but couldn't find the method in it. But in `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator::process()` i found a line like this `$rule->getActions()->validate($item)`